# mysql trigger after insert new line table1 copy to table2 selected fields without duplicates

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, triggers, phpmyadmin

I want to create trigger after inserting a new row on TABLE1 and a trigger for the update when I update table1.

I have 2 tables.

After I insert table1 information then I want to trigger copy some data to new row on table2. (In this case, F and G will be null and id2 is auto incrementing.)

id1, A, B, C, D, E = are the table1 columns.
id2, id1, C, E, F, G = are the table2 columns.
id1 and id2 are primary keys on each table

TABLE1(id1, A, B, C, D, E)

TABLE2(id2, id1, C, F, G)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(id1 INT, A VARCHAR(10), B VARCHAR(10), C date), D VARCHAR(10), E VARCHAR(10));                                      

CREATE TABLE Table2(id2 INT, C2 date, F VARCHAR(10), G VARCHAR(10));            

GO
CREATE TRIGGER Table1_AfterInsert
    AFTER INSERT ON Table1
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE Table2
    SET C2 = NEW.C
    WHERE id1 = NEW.id2;
END;
GO
INSERT INTO Table2(id2, F,G)VALUES(1,'111','red');
INSERT INTO Table2(id2, F,G)VALUES(2,'222','blue');
INSERT INTO Table2(id2, F,G)VALUES(3,'333','red');
GO
INSERT INTO Table1(id1, C)VALUES(1,'AAA'),(2,'BBB');
GO
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
GO
CREATE TRIGGER Table1_AfterUpdate
    AFTER UPDATE ON Table1
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF (OLD.C != NEW.C2)
    THEN
      UPDATE Table2
      SET C2 = NEW.C
      WHERE id2 = NEW.id1;
    END IF;
END;
GO
UPDATE TableA
```

At the moment I get all the rows copied to table2 if I remove for each row.
When I try to put for each row then getting an error.

THIS IS WITH MY REAL TABLE I GET NEAR LINE 7 ERROR #1064 SINTAX

```
  CREATE TABLE man_value(id (PK), nome_documento VARCHAR(10), descricao VARCHAR(10), data_fim date, data_inicio date, color VARCHAR(10), quem_fim VARCHAR(10), quem_inicio VARCHAR(10));                                        

    CREATE TABLE calendar(id (PK),id_man INT, end_date date, tiltle VARCHAR(10), description VARCHAR(10), color VARCHAR(10), created_by VARCHAR(10), create_at (datetime));         

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- THIS ONE IS WORKING OK
   DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER man_value_calendar_AfterInsert
    AFTER INSERT ON man_value
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN


      INSERT INTO calendar (id_man, title, end_date, description, color,create_by)
  VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.nome_documento, NEW.data_fim,NEW.descricao, '#FFD700',NEW.quem_fim);

END$$

DELIMITER ;

    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- NO ERROR BUT DOES NOTHING

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER man_value_calendar_AfterUpdate
    AFTER UPDATE ON man_value
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF (OLD.id = NEW.id)
    THEN
      UPDATE calendar
      SET id_man=NEW.id, title = NEW.nome_documento, end_date=NEW.data_fim, description=NEW.descricao, color='#FFD700', create_by=NEW.quem_fim
      WHERE id_man = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Untested but i believe it will be something like this. I'm asking since i have never done it before so not sure if there is easier  ot better. The previous code i tried and it copied all the table lines instead of just the inserted new line.

Comment: After insert works fine. After update sintax error not sure on SET sintax

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

CREATE TABLE man_value(id (PK), nome_documento VARCHAR(10), descricao VARCHAR(10), data_fim date, data_inicio date, color VARCHAR(10), quem_fim VARCHAR(10), quem_inicio VARCHAR(10));

```
CREATE TABLE calendar(id (PK),id_man INT, end_date date, tiltle VARCHAR(10), description VARCHAR(10), color VARCHAR(10), created_by VARCHAR(10), create_at (datetime));         

    ---------------------------------
   DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER man_value_calendar_AfterInsert
    AFTER INSERT ON man_value
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN


      INSERT INTO calendar (id_man, title, end_date, description, color,create_by)
  VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.nome_documento, NEW.data_fim,NEW.descricao, '#FFD700',NEW.quem_fim);

END$$

DELIMITER ;

    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER man_value_calendar_AfterUpdate
    AFTER UPDATE ON man_value
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF (OLD.id = NEW.id)
    THEN
      UPDATE calendar
      SET id_man=NEW.id, title = NEW.nome_documento, end_date=NEW.data_fim, description=NEW.descricao, color='#FFD700', create_by=NEW.quem_fim
      WHERE id_man = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```